# How to host a socket.io server and a http server together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a `Socket.io` server and a basic HTTP server that I coded together, but the problem is that the HTTP-server tries to serve requests that `socket.io` should serve.

Code:

```
//Dependences
var sio = require('socket.io');
var http = require("http");
var NewRequestHandler = require('./NewRequestHandler').Handler;
var DisconnectHandler = require('./DisconnectHandler').Handler;
var AuthorisationRequestHandler = require('./AuthorisationRequestHandler').Handler;
//The backlog of resources
var ResourceBackLog;

var ResourceRequestHandler = require("./ResourceRequestHandler").Handler;
//Reports the IP adress and Port that it will run on.
console.log('IP address: ' +  process.env.IP);
console.log('Port: ' + process.env.PORT);
//Creates and configures a new http.server instance.
var Server = new http.Server();

//Starts both the http and socket.io server.
var io = sio.listen(Server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, ResourceBackLog, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    } else if (!error) {
        console.log("Server started sucsessfully.");
        Server.on('request', ResourceRequestHandler);
        console.log("Server now ready for requests.");
    }
}));

//Handles the connect and authorisation bit
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('New Connection');
    socket.on('auth', function(Keys) {
    console.log('Autorisation Request Recived');
        AuthorisationRequestHandler(socket, Keys, function() {
            socket.on('NewRequest',  function(Request) {
                NewRequestHandler(socket, Request);
            });
            socket.on('diconnect', function() {
                DisconnectHandler(socket);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

The ResourceRequestHandler is the file that serves resources by checking the URL then opening the file at that location,
but it also serves /socket.io requests.

Comment: I find the examples on the socket.io website quite understandable
http://socket.io/#how-to-use
You should probably try and stick to the examples until you have to move away from them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.createServer(RequestHandler)` and  `new http.Server(RequestHandler)` work

Answer (score 0):

I would have Socket.io listen on another port and have the regular http server direct requests to it that way you can be sure they won't interfere with each other.

```
// create server
io = http.createServer();
 io.on('uncaughtException', function(exception) {
 console.log(exception);
});
io.listen(4001);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Socket.IO 0.9.6.

It is important to attach your custom request listener before the socket.io one. Socket.IO will then serve the requests it can and delegate all the others to your own request listener.

The algorithm in socket.io/lib/manger.js, is as follows.
In constructor:
1. remove all the existing request listeners.
2. attach Socket.IO request listener.
On request:
1. try to handle the request.
2. if Socket.IO cannot handle it, it delegates the request to the original listeners - those which were earlier removed in the constructor.